# Concatenate two model fields and produce sum field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

So I was trying to concatenate field A and field B which would result into field C. But I can't make it work. Can anyone enlighten me?

This is the model that I was using

```
class Claims(TimeStampedModel):
A = models.ForeignKey(
    'InsureePolicy', related_name='Insuree', on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

B = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

C = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: did you try  overriding the model's save method and typecasting A and  B to string and then concatenating ?

Comment: Why even have this as a field? ( It leads Unnecessary trouble of updating C every time A or B is updated) Just have it as a property.

Answer (score 0):

In your models save method ,

```
def save(self, *args , **kwargs):
    self.C= str(self.A) + str(self.B)
    super().save(*args , **kwargs)
```

Comment: if you don't check for null value it will return `None` in string btw

Comment: Thank you this worked. How ever I was trying to make the variable A as claims_id, but it shows none+B when viewing in Django admin

Comment: make sure you have defined the "def __str__(self) : " method for the foreign key model